# swift NSCoder dont decode in widget

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, today-extension, nscoder

I have a code that is executed in the host application and widget. All works in the main application, but one line in the widget - no

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "Name") as! String
    ip[0] =  UInt8(aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "IP0"))
    ip[1] =  UInt8(aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "IP1"))
    ip[2] =  UInt8(aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "IP2"))
    ip[3] =  UInt8(aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "IP3"))

    NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(LEDMode.self, forClassName: "LEDMode")
    if let saved = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "Mode") as? NSData {
        mode = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: saved as Data) as! [LEDMode]
    }

    client = getTCPClient(ip)
}
```

widget crash in this line
`mode = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: saved as Data) as! [LEDMode]`

message in debugger

2016-07-02 21:09:27.276947 LEDWidget[4616:272955] 
*** Terminatingapp due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException',
 reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: 
cannot decode object of class (LEDControl.SingleColor) for key (NS.objects); 
the class may be defined in source code or a library that is not linked

class SingleColor diclared

```
class SingleColor: LEDMode
```

class LEDMode diclared

```
class LEDMode: NSObject, NSCoding
```

Comment: @Dershowitz123 in SingleColor
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        for i in 0...2 {
            color[i] =  UInt8(aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "color\(i)"))
        }
    }

Comment: @Dershowitz123 if I add super.init() to LEDMode - error "Property 'self.client' not initiallized at super.init call"